# change punctuation after author and year as well as at the end of bibliography with apacite package

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, apacite, author

I want my references in the bibliography to look like this:

> Gamelin FX, Baquet G, Benoit S, Thevenet D, Nourry C, Nottin S, Bosquet L (2009)
>   Effect of high intensity intermittent training on heart rate variability in prepubescent children. Eur J Appl Physiol 105:731-738. doi: 10.1007/s00421-008-0955-8

At the moment my references Looks like this:

> Gamelin FX, Baquet G, Benoit S, Thevenet D, Nourry C, Nottin S, Bosquet L **.** (2009)**.** Effect of high intensity intermittent training on heart rate variability in prepubescent children. Eur J Appl Physiol 105:731-738. doi: 10.1007/s00421-008-0955-8 **.**

I.e. I want to remove the dots after author and year as well as at the end.

I would be very grateful for your help.

Also, I hope it is possible to change this within the `apacite` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the bibtex code for the entry in question; that way, would-be answer providers are spared the error-prone tedium of having to type in the entry by hand. Incidentally, the `apacite` package and bibliography style implement the APA6 guidelines "to the T". Modifying the file `apacite.bst` is probably an open invitation to formatting-related confusion. Before undertaking a modification of `apacite.bst`, you should probably consider whether older APA-related bibliography styles, such as `apalike` and `apalike2`, actually perform the formatting you require.